# custom binding to force Inner class creation or getters/setters for xs:element

Tags: binding, xsd, inner-classes, jaxb2, xjc

I have a schema declaration as follow from a third-party provider.

```
<xs:complexType name="GroupParameterType">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="4">
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>The name of the parameter.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>The value of the parameter.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Above is the schema that i CANNOT change. I am trying to write a custom binding for jaxb 2.0 such that I can refer to name as GroupParameterType.Name or GroupParameterType.Value in java code.

Current default binding generates List for me i.e. getNameandValueList, but I want separate getters and setters for name and value respectively.

I tried putting in a custom binding like the following :

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="GroupParameter.xsd" node="xs:element[@name='name']">
    <jxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel" generateIsSetMethod="true"/>
</jxb:bindings>
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="GroupParameter.xsd" node="xs:element[@name='value']">
    <jxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel" generateIsSetMethod="true"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

and it did nothing to change the default class generation. Can anyone give me some pointers as so what else can I try next ? I am looking to have the default List generation ALONG WITH the getters/setters for name and value OR have name and value as Inner Classes. If i remove the maxOccurs=4 option, I can generate getters/setters but since I can't modify the schema, I am trying to get that behavior using external binding file.

Thanks
Shon

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this behaviour unless you modify your schema. You do have a schema model which maps to a heterogeneous element property, and you can't change it with a customization.

You can try the [code injection plugin](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html) as the last retreat.